# How to show String from arrayList in textview in a specified interval of time?

Tags: android

I have an app in which i sent a server request and in response server send me a set of array and from that set of array I extract a string named as "dealname" and after that i have a textview in which i want to show this string every after 5 seconds like using Thread.sleep() and when arraycome to end i want to start from 1st array.How can I do that pls help.

here is the code i am trying

```
private CDealAppDatastorage item;
private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ArrayList<CDealAppDatastorage> s_oDataset;

try{
    String json;
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("dealcategory","DEALTEST");
    json = jsonObject.toString();
    Log.e(TAG,"Server Reqeust::-"+json);

    final String m_szTicker = "http://14.192.16.1555:8080/rest/json/metallica/getDealListsJSON?";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, m_szTicker,jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Server Response::"+response);
            try{

                if (response.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Transaction Successful")){
                    JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// get Deal list in array from r
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {// loop for counting deals from server
                        JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// counting deal based on index
                        item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// creating object of DealAppdata storage
                        item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));// get deal name from response
                        s_oDataset.add(item);// add all items in ArrayList

                    }
                    int i;
                    for (i=0;i<s_oDataset.size();i++){
                        Log.e(TAG,"Data Size:"+i);

                        final int finalI = i;
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                CDealAppDatastorage m = s_oDataset.get(finalI);
                                m_Text.setText(m.getM_szHeaderText());
                            }
                        },6000);

                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());// creating object of Request queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);// add json Object request to request queue
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop logic so it will start over again if the list ends.

```
int i;
int size = s_oDataset.size();
for (i=0;;i++){
                    Log.e(TAG,"Data Size:"+i);

                    final int finalI = i % size; //this will loop again from start if lists ends
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            CDealAppDatastorage m = s_oDataset.get(finalI);
                            m_Text.setText(m.getM_szHeaderText());
                        }
                    },6000);

                }
```

Comment: same for if there is image instead of textview

Comment: can you explain little about for (i=0;;i++)

Comment: here there is no loop termination condition. `i` will keep increasing but `i%size` will always give a no which is in range of list size.

Comment: sanjeet if you don't mind can you give me solution of one more

Comment: will try if I can

Comment: if the is a array like for image "logo":"c:/desktop/logo.png", how can i show that in imageview

Comment: this is in server response

Comment: You can use any library like picasso or UIL and set the image to imageView

Comment: there is system path not url

Comment: @Raghav then I don't think you can do like that. You need to find another way like changing the response or copy those images in drawable folder and based on response pick from there